# IIS, User Permissions and Umbraco

Tags: permissions, iis-7.5, ntfs, umbraco7

I have installed Umbraco on my local machine but I have some questions regarding IIS and permissions if someone can help verify that I understand it all correctly. My environment is as follows

•   Windows 7 Pro OS

•   IIS 7.5 - I have set up a new site in IIS which has the identity Application Pool Identity for the app pool

•   Umbraco v7.3.0 – The application files are located in C:\Users[myUsername]\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\InstallingUmbracoDemo\InstallingUmbracoDemo

Is the following process/understanding correct?

1. Add a new website in IIS and the application pool name is automatically updated to reflect my sites name.
2. By default this will use the identity ApplicationPoolIdentity which means that my new sites worker process (w3wp.exe) will run in an application pool that has the same name as my website in IIS
3. By default when I created my new site it will be added to a user group called IIS_IUSR
4. If I try to access my application files (that are in a folder that doesn’t not grant permission to the IIS_IUSR user group) it will mean IIS can’t access the resources until I grant the IIS_IUSR user group access
5. The IUSR user group is used for anonymous access and for anything anonymously requesting my website it will be added to this group
6. As Umbraco needs to access the internet to install the application I need to a grant permission to IUSR to allow it to do so

Partly because I don’t quite fully understand everything I’m quite concerned about the security of granting permission to IUSR on the root folder where the application files reside. Once Umbraco has installed can this user groups full permission be revoked? Does it require full permission?

I have found the following resource https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/permissions but if anyone else can provide an overview regarding permissions and the ISUR & IIS_ISUR work and more importantly whether I am understanding this process correctly.

Apologies if I am way of the mark – I’m just trying to learn and ensure i fully understand everything.

Many thanks
Paul

Comment: Does this mean my analysis is spot on ? 

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco will need permission to write files to certain folders on the server as the content/media cache, examine indexes, logs, media, etc are all disk file based.

Have you tried adding the specific AppPool user to the folders and granting permission to it?

Its usually:

IIS AppPool\MyAppPoolNameInIIS

I have had cases where that isn't allowed and I have to use IUSR, but generally this works and seems more specific and contained.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back. Is it better practice to only assign the specific app pool permission to the application files? Do all application pools that use application pool identity get added to the IIS_IUSRS groups by default. If so giving access to this group should also be ok right?

Comment: Yea, I that should work as well.  I guess it just depends on how separated your want the permissions to be.  I just figured more specific was better from a security perspective, but I don't have any data to back that up.  I know we use the more generic user groups as well from time to time.